# how do i solve NSRangeException into swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9.2, nsrangeexception

I am working on app where I using swift 4. But when I want to go from first viewcontroller to second viewcontroller I got this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'**

I tried to go from first viewcontroller to second viewcontroller on button click using like bellow

```
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

But when I clicked button my app get crashed and get above nsrangeexception error

So how do I solve this error any other solution to go from first vc to second vc?

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: What is the parent class of `NextViewController`

Comment: @CharlesSrstka sorry i am new in swift 4 so i got only this error and my app is going to crash.

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes UIViewController

Comment: can you share `NextViewController` code?

Comment: @Kamran sorry but i used gif animation and label which change text what i passed some value from my previous viewcontroller but now i am not passing anything any string so is that any problem because when i try to another viewcontroller to go their with some label value it is possible to go that viewcontroller

Comment: @mab When the app crashes, get the backtrace and add it to your answer. Without more information it is not possible even to know what is actually crashing.

Comment: Your code shouldn't crash. I think that the issue is on the code of `NextViewController`. You have an `Array` there? You might do in it a "indexOfObject" search, and since you don't check if it's found (the high number should be a NSNotFound), you crash. Show the code of `NextViewController` or at least the full error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that your `NextViewController` has Storyboard ID in the storyboard:

[image]

And check that you're loading storyboard correctly:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate through Controller on StoryBoard with Identifier `"nextView"`, then do this(this will applicable when you are trying to show one storyboard's `ViewController` to another storyboard `ViewController`):

```
   let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
   let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! NextViewController
   self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

**OR** If you are in same storyBoard then you can simply do this -
Take a button in your `firstVC` and `ctrl+ drag` a segue upto your `secondVC`. Then click on the segue. (the round thing on between two view controller). -

[image]

And set a identifier for that (here `about` is the identifier, you can give any name for this)-

[image]

Here is the code -

```
@IBAction func UserDetailVC(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifierName(about)", sender: sender)
    }
```